# Optimization needed: Reformat string with optional and repeatable patterns using regex

Tags: php, regex, optimization

I want to reformat a string in PHP using regular expressions.

The string can look like this: (e.g.)

```
bj-11_2008-06_2015(F01,F02,F03,F04)
bj-11_2008-06_2015(F01)
bj-11_2008-06_2015(01)
bj-11_2008-06_2015(3B)
bj-11_2008-06_2015
bj-11_2008
```

Let's go through this:

First part is mandatory `bj-11_2008` and the `bj`is fixed the `11_2008` could be any date in the format of `MM_YYYY`
Second part is optional `-06_2015`, again should be `MM_YYYY`
The parentheses are also optional `(3B)` but if it's there should at least contain one entry but up to n.
Every entry should be up to 4 uppercase letters and/or digits and separated by "," like: `(F01,F02,F03,F04)`.

Then everything should be reformatted like this:

1. The `bj-` gets removed
2. Underscores "_" in dates are replaced with pipes "|"
3. spaces around dash "-"
4. space after second date
5. Replace "," with ";"

Example output:

```
11|2008 - 06|2015 (F01;F02;F03;F04)
```

This is what I got already:

The regex:

```
bj-([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{4})[-]*([0-9]{2})?_?([0-9]{4})?([(]([[:alnum:]]{0,4},?)*[)])?
```

https://regex101.com/r/R7R3jC/1

PHP:

```
$regex = "/bj-([0-9]{2})_([0-9]{4})[-]*([0-9]{2})?_?([0-9]{4})?([(]([[:alnum:]]{0,4},?)*[)])?/";
$teststrings=array(
        "bj-11_2008-06_2015(F01,F02,F03,F04)",
        "bj-11_2008-06_2015(F01)",
        "bj-11_2008-06_2015(01)",
        "bj-11_2008-06_2015(3B)",
        "bj-11_2008-06_2015",
        "bj-11_2008"
    );

foreach ($teststrings as $teststring) {

    echo preg_replace_callback($regex, function($matches) {
            $regexp2 = "/([[:alnum:]]{0,4},?)/";
            $string ="";
            
            if (isset($matches[5])) {
                $string = "(";
                preg_match_all($regexp2, $matches[5], $inner_matches, PREG_SET_ORDER);
                
                foreach($inner_matches as $match){
                    $string .= "$match[0]";
                }
                $string .= ")";
                $string = str_replace(",",";",$string);
            }
            
            if (isset($matches[4])){
                echo "$matches[1]|$matches[2] - $matches[3]|$matches[4]" . " $string<br>";
            } 
            else {
                echo "$matches[1]|$matches[2]";
            }
        }
    , $teststring);
}
```

http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/12b77482508f9d41e8b27a8c4df57bf47914155e

This works but I think is relatively complex and could probably be simplified and optimized. But this was all that I was able to make with my very limited knowledge on regular expressions
Can you help me?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since your original string is already formatted and this format is known, you don't have explore it with a regex pattern, you can do it with a simple replacement:

```
$s = <<<'EOD'
bj-11_2008-06_2015(F01,F02,F03,F04)
bj-11_2008-06_2015(F01)
bj-11_2008-06_2015(01)
bj-11_2008-06_2015(3B)
bj-11_2008-06_2015
bj-11_2008
EOD;

$trans = [ 'bj-' => '', '_' => '|', '-' => ' - ', '(' => ' (',
           ',' => ';' ];

echo strtr($s, $trans);
```

[demo](https://3v4l.org/kaMqQ)

Comment: This just made 3 lines of code out of my 22, and seems to work just as expected, thank you.
https://3v4l.org/sZN1N

Answer (score 0):

Without any regex, only some substrings used:

```
$input='bj-11_2008-06_2015(F01,F02,F03,F04)';

$s1=$s2=$s3='';

$sub = substr($input,3,7);                // => 11_2008
$s1 = str_replace('_','|',$sub);          // => 11|2008

$sub = substr($input,11,7);               // => 06_2015
if($sub !== false){
   $s2 = ' - '.str_replace('_','|',$sub); // => - 06|2015
   }

$sub = substr($input,18);                 // => (F01,F02,F03,F04)
if($sub !== false){
   $s3 = str_replace(',',';',$sub);       // =>  (F01;F02;F03;F04)
   }

$result = $s1.$s2.$s3;                    // => 11|2008 - 06|2015 (F01;F02;F03;F04)
```